# Why should variance(output) equal variance(input) in Xavier Initialisation?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, feedforward-neural-networks, weights, weights-initialization

In a lot of explanations online for Xavier Initialization, I see the following:

> With each passing layer, we want the variance to remain the same. This helps us keep the signal from exploding to a high value or vanishing to zero. In other words, we need to initialize the weights in such a way that the variance remains the same for x and y. This initialization process is known as Xavier initialization.

Source https://prateekvjoshi.com/2016/03/29/understanding-xavier-initialization-in-deep-neural-networks/

However, the intuition behind why var(output) should equal var(inputs) is never explained. Does anyone know why intuitively var(output) should equal var(inputs)?

Comment: I have asked also this question and no answers are given. All the posts/blogs just refer to this but never touch on why this must be the case. Have you checked the original paper if they provide a justification?